# Saving permanent data using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android

I am making a Highscore script for my game using Shared Preferences. I want this data to be only held for the phone it is installed on obviously. I have done the following, and the highscore shows and updates, but when I close out of the app and re open it, it resets.

```
            if(finalScore > SharedPrefManager.getHighScore())
            SharedPrefManager.SetHighScore(finalScore);             
            SharedPrefManager.StoreToPref();
```

SharedPrefManager.java:

```
package com.divergent.thumbler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

// all methods are static , so we can call from any where in the code
//all member variables are private, so that we can save load with our own fun only
public class SharedPrefManager {
//this is your shared preference file name, in which we will save data
public static final String MY_EMP_PREFS = "MySharedPref";  

//saving the context, so that we can call all 
//shared pref methods from non activity classes. 
//because getSharedPreferences required the context.
//but in activity class we can call without this context
private static Context     mContext; 

// will get user input in below variables, then will store in to shared pref
private static int         HighScore             = 0;

public static void Init(Context context)
{
    mContext         = context;
}
public static void LoadFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings     = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0);
    // Note here the 2nd parameter 0 is the default parameter for private access,
    //Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation,
    HighScore = settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);

}
public static void StoreToPref()
{
    // get the existing preference file
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("HighScore", HighScore); // Age is the key and mAge is holding the value

    //final step to commit (save)the changes in to the shared pref
    editor.commit(); 
}

public static void DeleteSingleEntryFromPref(String keyName)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove(keyName);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void DeleteAllEntriesFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}


public static void SetHighScore(int score)
{
    HighScore = score;
}

public static int getHighScore()
{
    return HighScore ;
}
}
```

Comment: Your tags are different , see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better don't store sensitive information in `sharedpreference`. All the users that have root permission can see and easily edit your `sharedpreference`(If it is not encrypted). So dont forget to encrypt all data.

Here is the chunk of code you need to store in `sharedpreference`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("finalScore", yourscore);
editor.commit();
```

**UPDATE**

You are setting as

```
editor.putInt("HighScore", HighScore);
```

and getting as

```
HighScore = settings.getInt("Age",0);
```

You should use the same tag

**UPDATE**

Change

```
HighScore = settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);
```

to

```
settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);
```

Comment: Where do I put that code? And how do I add encryption? Im pretty new to java

Comment: Have a look in to `http://viswanathl.blogspot.in/2014/01/encryption-and-decryption-using-aes-in.html` You should encrypt the tag and value , so that user cant get what that is

Comment: I changed the tags to match and that didnt solve it. Where do I need to put the other code above.

Comment: Thanks :) Also that link u entered for the encryption doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55319/discussion-between-divergent-and-viswanath-l).